# How can we give access to certain user in Excel sheet using sharepoint list

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I have an Excel list consist of 10 rows
In that, one user can only access 5 rows, another user can access another 5 rows and another user can access a total of 10 rows.
So how can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through VBA Macro however if you dont prefer VBA, the simplest way to give different level of access is to define "Allow Users to Edit Ranges" and protect the Sheet

You can access this settings through the ribbon Review -> Allow User to Edit Ranges

1. Click New
2. Give some Title to the Range, Select the appropriate Range, provide Range Password and click OK.
3. Share the password with the user who can edit the range
4. If you require more ranges, repeat the same steps (1-3)

Thanks,